# Dynamically change grid parameter based on search

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid in which when I use the single search and do not find any records in the grid then I want to do either one of these thing

- Change pgtext to show "0 of 0"
- Hide pgbutton

I tried following things but it did not work.

```
$('#userList').setGridParam({pginput:false}).trigger('reloadGrid',[{page:1}]);
$('#userList').jqgrid('setGridParam',{pginput:false}).trigger('reloadGrid',[{page:1}]);
$('#userList').jqgrid().setGridParam({pginput:false}).trigger('reloadGrid',[{page:1}]);
```

I tried adding one of the above line to either onSearch / loadComplete / gridComplete events. The grid reload is not triggered and the pginput box is not hidden.

Can anyone tell me how can I hide the pgbutton at runtime or change the pgtext to "0 of 0".

`Solution which worked for me.`

I got the class for the page number text box and using jquery changed the value of that textbox to zero when search returned zero records. The code which worked for me is

```
$("input:text.ui-pg-input").val(0);
```

Hope this solution helps others.

Comment: When no records are found, the record count will display `No records found` and the pager buttons will be grayed out/disabled. This happens by default - no need to change anything.

Comment: Thats right`@FastTrack` but I need to hide the page number input box between the pager button when no records are found. Or show "0 of 0" instead of "1 of 0"